# Click on a div (with classname of table id) to display hidden div (with same classname of table id)

Tags: php, jquery, for-loop

So my database has a table with one column `id`. My `index.php` page echos out all the database rows of `id` in individual divs.

The class name of button element clicked on is:

`"mainbut<?php echo $id->rqvid; ?>"`

And the class name of the hidden div element is:

`"subdiv<?php echo $id->rqvid; ?>"`

What I want to achieve is when `mainbut<?php echo $id->rqvid; ?>` is clicked on, then `subdiv<?php echo $id->rqvid; ?>` shows. In simpler terms - when a button(with row `id`) is clicked on, then a hidden div(with same row `id`) shows.

A visual representation of what I want achieved:

Note: The four `1`'s represents the row of the column `id` from the database

```
----------------
| 1 [mainbut1] | <-- when [mainbut1] is clicked on
----------------
| 1 (subdiv1)  | <-- then div of classname "subdiv1" shows
----------------
```

So for example I have 3 rows with id's numbered 1  to 3 from my table. But when I click on any of the buttons, it will not display the hidden div element *of the same id*. Instead, it displays only one hidden div element *of the last row `id`*. So this is the result I am getting:

```
----------------
| 1 [mainbut1] | <-- when [mainbut1] is clicked on...
----------------
                 <-- (div "subdiv1" does not show. Why?)
----------------
| 2 [mainbut2] | 
----------------
----------------
| 3 [mainbut3] |
----------------
| 3 (subdiv3)  | <-- But instead div "subdiv3" shows.
----------------
```

I want to be able to click any of the buttons and *only its corresponding hidden div with the **same id** shows*. There is definitely something I am missing from my jquery code I think. Can someone help me get this to work right? Here is the current code I have:

```
<?php foreach($ids as $id): ?>
<div>
    <?php echo $id->rqvid; ?>
    <button class="mainbut<?php echo $id->rqvid; ?>">click</button>
</div>

<div class="subdiv<?php echo $id->rqvid; ?>">
    <?php echo $id->rqvid; ?> sub-box
</div>

<script>
var i = '<?php echo $id->rqvid; ?>';
$(".mainbut"+i).on('click', function() {
    $(".subdiv"+i).css("display","block");
});
</script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply generate something like the following HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($ids as $id) { ?>
<button onclick="$('#subdiv_<?php echo $id->rqvid ?>').toggle();">
    toggle ID <?php echo $id->rqvid ?>
</button>

<div id="subdiv_<?php echo $id->rqvid ?>">
    ID <?php echo $id->rqvid ?>: sub-box
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Explanation: jQuery's `$('#element_id')` returns an element with the ID `element_id` and the call to `toggle()` on that element toggles the element's visibility. Just make sure to have unique IDs the same way you are generating class names.

You can test the frontend part [here](https://repl.it/@ferenczy/jQuery-element-visibility-toggle).

P.S.: It's not about PHP, it's just an HTML and jQuery problem.